Flutter How to design a custom container with a some circle cut inside and apply shadow on it
This is my design in figma.. as you can see, i want to design container exactly like that with a square on the left and some cut and another rectangle at the right... all of this combined to become 1 widget and supposed to have shadow below it... is it possible to achieve this?

